# Proxy ActiveSync Between Domains

Tags: exchange-2010, iphone, activesync

We are a subsidiary of our parent company. We have all of our own infrastructure and AD domain. All users connect to our domain for all resources except email which is provided by out parent.

What have been asked is can we provide a way of offering email to iPhone directly from our infrastructure? I guess i'm looking for something that would proxy activesync connections to our parents exchange environment.

Below is a very high level of what the environment looks like. There are no domain trusts nor do we have any administrative access to the exchange environment in parent.com. They provide us with email in a subdomain aust.parent.com.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhVND.png

Effectively we would like users on iPhone's to come into a 'activesync proxy' in our DMZ, proxy the connection to the parent's exchange server and allow the user access to the email.

There are internal reasons at why we are looking at this and understand the security implications we might encounter.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

EAS ils http based, so any http proxy would do the job. Nginx is probably a good choice to proxy applications using long living connections.